# Resources for SharePoint Development

Tags: sharepoint

I have to develop an appliction (Asp.Net - maybe MVC) that would be integrated into SharePoint 3.0. This is the first time I have anything to do with SharePoint and I'd like to pick up the basics quickly. I haven't found any reasonable online resources - do you know any? 
Unfortunately, I don't have time to buy and read a book.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Creating and Deploying SharePoint Solution Files](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/40007/1954)

[SharePoint 2007 Deployment: Overview](http://blogit.create.pt/blogs/andrevala/archive/2007/12/02/SharePoint-2007-Deployment_3A00_-Overview.aspx)

[Tech Talk with Brett Maytom](http://grounding.co.za/blogs/brett/default.aspx)

[Sharepoint is not a good development platform](http://codebetter.com/blogs/jeffrey.palermo/archive/2007/09/13/sharepoint-is-not-a-good-development-platform.aspx)  - This will give you a good idea of what to expect and what NOT to expect from SharePoint.

[Todd Bleeker's Blog](http://sharepoint.mindsharpblogs.com/Todd/default.aspx)

[Tobias Zimmergren](http://www.zimmergren.net/default.aspx)

That's all I can think of for a start. If you have more specific questions I can direct you to different resources.

Answer (score 2):

When you say integrate do you mean simply have it available inside of sharepoint?
If so then you don't need any books or tutorials it is **very simple** to embed your apps into sharepoint.  We do this all of the time due to limitations within sharepoint.  We write our ASP.net apps and use a web site web part that allows you to enter some basic information (such as the location of the web site) into the web part and then it is displayed right within sharepoint.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right sharepoint can provide you with additional "web parts" such as header information, footer information, or even links on the left or right side of the Sharepoint portal.  Yes this works for ASP.net MVC as well.

Comment: Thanks Jon. So, when you enbed you application into SharePoint, does it only provide some GUI elements such as a header, footer and navigation or is there something more you get from it? Also, would that work with ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: This approach is really just dropping your application into an iframe on the SharePoint site, which exactly as you said, is fine if you're only looking to keep the navigation in tact. If you're wanting to do any SharePointy things integrated with your existing app you'll need a different approach.